# Is there any way to obtain a Spotify Premium account for testing?

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm developing an iOS app using Cocoalibspotify. Last week I submitted it to the App Store. A few days later I received a message saying that they cannot test my app without a test account. Is there any way that I can obtain a test premium spotify account or do I have to create a new 30 day free trial account for them to test? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way of getting a second Premium account for testing. If you're unwilling to give your own account details to Apple, a trial account is probably the best way to go.

Comment: If I give them access to a premium account, they won't see all my credit card infos, will they?

Comment: even if they enter your profile page, your credit card details are encrypted. They would only be able to see the last four digits. It's highly unlikely a company like Apple would do such a thing which could cause a huge PR disaster.